# Intercept gsm data in ios

Tags: ios, gsm, iphone-privateapi

I want to do some treatment of the gsm data in ios before it sent. i know that i have to use private APi and in my case its not a problem, my app is experimental and will not be sent to the AppStor.
i dont know from where to begin.
I think that i will have those problems:

- Install/use private framework on xcode.
- No official documentation for that APIs, but i think with Cydia, many people use them.

Have you some tutorial or link that can help me to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be good idea to divide this question on two subquestions:

1) How to use private API

You can check following questions for info on this subject:

[How to use iPhone SDK Private APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838656/how-to-use-iphone-sdk-private-apis)

http://aralbalkan.com/2106

[iOS Private API Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150360/ios-private-api-documentation)

[Getting signatures of private API methods for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511570/getting-signatures-of-private-api-methods-for-ios)

If you will have any additional questions on. You can post it here or send me an email (I have it in my profile).

2) How to intercept gsm data using private api?

I don't know.

Three question for youL

- Did you really mean "gsm" data (gsm protocol level information) or did you mean wireless data (let say HTTP requests which are send from device)?
- Do you need to intercept and modify or do you need just intercept and view them?

If you meant wireless data and just viewing it then try to search for traffic sniffers. Some of them should work on iOS.

One more note. As soon as I hear "intercept" my guess would be that you will be better off with jailbreak tweak (vs private API). Private API's are limited in usage. Is this ok, if your app will work only on jailbroken devices?

Comment: GSM level information (despite some well known status values) is AFAIK not available on the iOS level as that is handled in an entirely different subsystem of the phone.

Comment: Thank you, Yes i mean GSM data not a 'voip' data, i think that i will have latecy problem(because the treatment), other thing is the detection of the input GSM data (normal or modified).  You say that instead using private API is better to use tweeks, I thoughtbthat tweeks use private APIs so its other possibility to consIder. If you have other links for using tweeks that will be great.

Comment: I believe you will have problems with getting GSM level information. I believe it's executed on separate processor. You should check http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/ and http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page
jailbreak tweaks work only on jailbroken devices and they are based on code injection in Apple system processes (and they can use private API). Purely Private API are just API which aren't documented by Apple and they can run on non jailbroken devices.

Comment: Here are couple of links for jailbreak tweeks: http://www.redmondpie.com/iosopendev-offers-xcode-templates-for-developing-jailbreak-appstweaks-v1.0.1-now-available-for-download/ http://fenix-tech.com/how-to-develop-jailbreak-tweaks-for-cydia-using-theos-on-ios-part-2/